# Trouble With Doubly Linked List Recursive

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures

I'm having trouble doing recursive deletion, Currently I'm able to delete 1 node at a time when I'm supposed to delete all the matches. I'm not able to delete all instances in a loop.

```
void delete(struct node *ptr){
    struct node *tmp; 
    while(ptr->next != NULL && (ptr->next)->critical = 'c'){
        ptr = ptr->next; //Iterate until I find a node next to data
    }
    if(ptr->next == NULL){
        printf("No Element");
    }
    tmp = ptr->next;
    if(tmp->next == NULL){
        ptr->next = NULL;
    } else {
        ptr->next = tmp->next;
        (ptr->next)->prev = tmp->prev;
    }
    tmp->prev = ptr;
    free(tmp);
}
```

**Working Update**
I just had to put all this inside another while(ptr != NULL){... ptr = ptr->next} loop for the recursive deletion.

Comment: when `ptr->next` is null you assign tmp the value of null and then dereference it go access next on it, which will cause an exception - not sure if that is your problem but it is definitely worth a look

Comment: do you really want this to be an assignment? `while(ptr->next != NULL && (ptr->next)->critical = 'c'){` or should it be an equality comparison? `while(ptr->next != NULL && (ptr->next)->critical =='c'){`

Comment: assuming the some in the list are already marked "c" we check for them and delete other than them

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code
The corrected code is

```
void delete(struct node *ptr){
    struct node *tmp; 
    while(ptr)
   {
    if(ptr->critical!='c')
        {tmp=ptr;
        ptr=ptr->next;
        ptr->prev=null;
        free(tmp);}
     else
       break;

   }
    while(ptr->next!=null)
    {
      if(ptr->next->critical=='c')
        ptr=ptr->next;
      else
       {
           tmp = ptr->next;
           if(tmp->next == NULL){
             ptr->next = NULL;
           } else {
            ptr->next = tmp->next;
           (ptr->next)->prev = tmp->prev;
           }
          tmp->prev = ptr;
          free(tmp);
       }
    }
```

see the corrections in the code

I first remove the required values from the beginning of the list. 
Then i continue deleting the values until i reach last node.
The problem with your code was that whenever you deleted a value you didnt checked for other values in the list.

Comment: It is == 'c' , so we are finding the ones near the critical and setting them to tmp and deleting the rest but with the code I posted I'm only able to do it 1 node I want to able to do i recursively.

Comment: No, that is not the problem, The update code is also just the same as I posted but a return statement.

Comment: please let me know if u still face some problem

Comment: The code you provided goes into some sort of an Infinity Loop. I found the solution for my problem, please look at the updated post.